# attach word document from folder, c# mail message

Tags: c#, asp.net, attachment, sendmail

I am trying to attach a word file from one of the folders in the website. 
This is how I am trying:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(msg.Attachments.Add(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Docs\" + companyName + ".doc")));
```

I am getting these errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>.Add(System.Net.Mail.Attachment)' has some invalid arguments 
cannot convert from 'void' to 'string'  
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.Attachment'
```

Any idea how I can solve this?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Docs\" + companyName + ".doc");
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(path);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Attachment a = new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Docs\" + companyName + ".doc"));
msg.Attachments.Add(a);
```